# How many different three-digit numbers satisfy the given property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

A three-digit number is given. The sum of all different three-digit numbers with the same digits as the given number (including the given number) is 1998 . How many different three-digit numbers satisfy the given property?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  The obvious first thought would be to introduce variables representing the digits and reduce the given information to an equation in those variables.

Comment: Note:  you'll want to specify whether or not you allow $0$ as a first digit.  For instance, $801$ works if you allow the sum to be $801+810+108+180+18+81$, but not if you don't allow the last two summands.  In a similar spirit, would you consider $18$, say, as a "good" three digit number and therefore count it in your problem or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add your thought process. I can give you only direction to think.
Consider the number to be xyz. Now find number such possible numbers by considering all cases (such as x,y,z all distinct, any two same or all same).
For all distinct, sum of all numbers made from x,y,z will be $$200(x+y+z) + 20(x+y+z) + 2(x+y+z) = (222)(x+y+z) = 1998$$
Calculate all possible values of {x,y,z} and do the same for other cases.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for correcting. Each digit will appear twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If all the digits are different, then there are $3! = 6$ different numbers and you also know that the value of a number $xyz$ is $100x + 10y + z$. So sum up all such numbers and case-bash.

If $2$ digits are the same, there are $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ different numbers, and you can do similar as above.

If all digits are the same, there is only one such number, but since $1998$ is a $4$-digit number, this case doesn't work.